# MouseEvent is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

So i have this code which i'm working on as a school project once again and i ran into some trouble finding out the error i had and how to fix it.

So eclipse gives me an error:

The method setOnMouseEntered(EventHandler) in the type Node is not applicable for the arguments (new EventHandler(){})
    Bound mismatch: The type MouseEvent is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type EventHandler

---

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Circle ring1 = new Circle(100, 100, 100, Color.RED); 
        ring1.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                System.out.println("Hiir läks ringi peale");
            }
        }
        );
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        root.getChildren().add(ring1);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Check your imports and make sure you have javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent, and not the awt MouseEvent.

Comment: Thank you, had .awt there..